# How to remove id from URL

Tags: php

I'd like to remove the customer Id from the URL for security measure. Currently when I click on a row in a table, the customers page will appear. The URL of the customer page will display the following.

http://localhost/test/view_customer?customer_id=12&operation=edit

The row displaying the customer details uses the following code to link to the customer page

`onclick="window.location='view_customer?customer_id=<?php echo htmlentities ($row['id']) ?>&operation=edit';"`

how do I avoid echoing the customer_id, but also have the data available? Would it possible to do this using $_POST? How would I go about editing my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could:

1. Encrypt `customer_id` along with it's value and can keep it in url
2. Store `customer_id` in php session
3. Rewrite URLs using `.htaccess` (url can become `xyz.com/view_customer/12/edit`)

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Ahhh... very smart! Do you have any Encryption protocols in mind? Any where I could learn encryption?

Comment: @Joe, you can try [openssl-encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) and [openssl-decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php) OR simple [base64-encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [base64-decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) Check this [tutorial](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/two-way-encryption/) or [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_crypt.asp)